# Get mouse relative position to dropped div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can get the absolute position of the mouse with:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        window.x = e.pageX;
        window.y = e.pageY;
    });
```

How can I get this position relative to a specific div?

Comment: Your question content and title seem different. If you bind to the document, what's the "parent" ?

Comment: check the jquery docs for mousemove: http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

Comment: @dystroy: The title is bad, you are right. On mousedown I need the coordenates relative to the dropped div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the offset of the div :

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    var offset = $(yourdiv).offset();
    window.x = e.pageX - offset.left;
    window.y = e.pageY - offset.top;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just subtract the clientX and ClientY from the offsetLeft and offsetTop of the div